# Checking Latency of a SQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, latency

So I have written a Java class where I connect to MySQL database using JDBC, and I have a query:

```
select name from hr order by rand() limit 1;
```

What I am trying to do is check the latency, so I was wondering if there was a better way of me checking the latency or more ways than currently:

```
String query = "select name from hr order by rand() limit 1;";
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String value = rs.getString("name");
        }

        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = (endTime - startTime);
        double seconds = (double)duration / 1000000000.0;
        System.out.println(seconds);
    }
```

Comment: Use a tool like wireshark to measure latency rather than doing it in your code directly. OT: interesting avatar.

Comment: you're timing not just the query execution time, but how long it'll take to fetch the results. Usually people are only concerned about query execution time, e.g. "how long does it take to get ANY results".

Comment: `order by rand()` is often bad news for stats

Comment: Marc: how would I go about finding the query execution time itself; would that be more similar to the fetch time shown in MySQL Workbench? I currently have this .java file being used in Windows but also need to use it in an EC2 linux server

Comment: Alex: that was one of my concerns, I read another page where it said it was bad for large amounts of data, which is why I am creating this latency test, is because I am testing a databases' efficiency with large amounts of data